# Preview is not properly showing

Tags: android, xml

In Android Studio 3.0 in Ubuntu 17.10.

I am designing ***.xml** file in **code view**  and i have changed **Root** from `ScrollView` to `RelativeLayout` and the preview is suddenly corrupted like this...

[image: like this]

and when i Run the project it gives correct output

[image: like this (This is Right)]

This is my `*.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvJoinTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/join_us"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvJoinTitle"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/country"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="BUSINESS COUNTRY"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/etcountryname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/country"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/gray_border"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/_1sdp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llSelectCountry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivCountryFlag"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_35sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    tools:src="@color/colorPrimary" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_1sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_23sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@color/gray" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etcountryselect"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvJoinUsName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etcountryname"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="@string/business_person_name"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llJoinUsName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvJoinUsName"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/gray_border"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/_1sdp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etJoinUsName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="@drawable/product_black_border"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="@dimen/_12sdp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvJoinUsMobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/llJoinUsName"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="@string/mobile_number"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llJoinUsMobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvJoinUsMobile"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/product_black_border"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llSelectCountryNum"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivCountryFlagNum"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_35sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:src="@color/colorPrimary" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtCountryCode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:text="+9000"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_1sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_23sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@color/gray" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etJoinUsMobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvJoinUsPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/llJoinUsMobile"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="@string/password"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/transportnumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/llJoinUsMobile"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="TRANSPORT REFERENCE NUMBER"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ettransportnumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/transportnumber"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_dotted_border"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_38sdp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/ettransportnumber"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10ssp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:onClick="goAndAddInfo"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried changing API level, Device, Theme, Orientation, Deleting build folders and even Invalid cache and Restart but no use.

i have faced this problem many times but dont know how to solve this.

Comment: I suggested to change the `Theme` in the Preview of Android Studio but you said it didn't work...

Comment: right, it didn't.

Comment: may be issue is loading preview, try to close layout and open again, if not work then restart your android studio

Comment: see my edits @NiranjPatel

Comment: Code seems perfect, it' showing properly at my side, Please Share screenshots of android studio.

Comment: _Please Share screenshots of android studio_ , what screenshot ?@NiranjPatel

Comment: screenshots of full window not only preview section.

Comment: the problem?...

Comment: here is the full windows screenshot [https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUdj3.png] @NiranjPatel

Comment: try to set white background of your root layout and check

Comment: Sorry, but  didn't work @NiranjPatel

Answer (score 0):

Not an issue from your XML of course. Try changing API level or may be the selected theme in the menu above preview window.